# I switched my internal storage to Sd card and it still won't let me download apps

Tags: sd-card

My phone has little to no space so I used an sd card as internal storage. It says I don't have enough storage even though the sd card has 30 gigabytes left.

Comment: How did you "use an sd card as internal storage"? What device and what version of Android you are using? Do you have root access? Please elaborate by editing question.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably still overloaded.

The option to use SD Card as internal storage is slowly disappearing because it avoids using the permissions for external storage and allows applications unrestricted access to every sector on the card, so expect it to disappear in newer Android versions.

**If you are using a device that allows what you've mentioned.**

The Applications installed prior to the switch over will still be on your internal storage, allso all of your stuff like photos, music, videos will still be consuming space on the internal storage, this will impact performance significantly on some devices.

**You need to move all your applications to SD first.**

- Open Settings
- Open Apps ( Samsung's it's More > Apps )
- Select the first downloaded Application
- Select Move to SD Card

  **NO OPTION FOR MOVE ( GREY )**
- The developer has selected Internal Storage Only, so you can't do anything with this, move on to the next one.

**Move All Files Over To SD Card**
You can find apps for automatically doing this.

- Open your Stock File Manager
- Navigate to Your Old Storage ( may be Internal or External )
- Select All Folders and Files in the root directory of the Old storage
- Copy All Folders and Files to the New storage  ( largest generally - the SD Card )
- Once you've waited 50 years for it to copy, you can safely Delete everything on the Old storage ( free up the space )
- Don't MOVE the Files and Folders in case something goes wrong, you'll still have it ready for copying again.

Now you should have some free storage back on your device.